# Understanding Skrollr data values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, skrollr

I am trying to understand the Skrollr javascript script library, and am having difficulty understanding data values, and how they differ between absolute and relative.

I have a background image on a div (about 2x taller than the div) that I would like to scroll down as I scroll down the page. Here is what I have so far.

```
<div id="jumbotron" data-top="background-position: right bottom;" data-bottom="background-position: right top;" >
```

What are data-top and data-bottom? As near as I can figure from the documentation, data-top is the top of the div #jumbotron. What I want is that when #jumbotron is at the top of the viewport, the background position is right bottom. Then, as I scroll and the the bottom of #jumbotron reaches the top of the viewport, I want the background image to be right top. This isn't happening. What am i doing  wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The skrollr library will transition the CSS on an element based on its data elements. For example, if you had an element as follows:

```
<div id="element" data-0="opacity: 1" data-100="opacity: 0"></div>
```

At scroll position 0 (user has not scrolled), the opacity of the element would be 1. Once the user has scrolled 100px down the page, the element would have faded to opacity 0. You can add as many data increments as you'd like.

Regarding data-top, the readme on the [skrollr repo](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) says the following:

> **data-top**: When the element's top is aligned with the top of the 
>   viewport

I don't however see anything about data-bottom in the docs. I only see:

> **data-top-bottom**: When the bottom of the element is at the top of the viewport (it's just not visible).

So you might try:

```
<div id="jumbotron" data-top="background-position: right bottom;" data-top-bottom="background-position: right top;" >
```

Just consider that the first data is your starting point, and the final data is your finishing point with as many increments along the way as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Skrollr.js needs a data-attribute with two values.
The first describes the alignment to the viewport.
The second the edge (or center) of the element.
It can be a bit confusing, that both are named in the same manner (top, center or bottom).

You can further position the background with percentage values.
This way skrollr can transition between the values.

See this example.
https://jsfiddle.net/4frjantk/

```
<div class='section' 
    data-bottom-top="background-position: 50% 100%" 
    data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% 0%" >
</div>
```

PS:
The example contains a workaround for containers with 100% height as described here https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/347